# Are there functions/commands available that will help multiple scripts execute to a certain point and proceed?

Tags: python, perl, bash, synchronization

I am looking for a mechanism to sync between scripts (bash or perl or Python) My requirement is as follows

Scripts a, b and c will start (not necessarily at the same time).  Once a, b, or c hits a certain point in the script, it should stop for other scripts to hit the same point.  For the sake of discussion lets call these as syncpoints.  Once the syncpoint is hit, by all scripts, all scripts can proceed to next syncpoint or end of script

Here is an example

Script a

```
task1
task2
task3
syncpoint 1
task4
task5
syncpoint 2
```

Script 2

```
task1
syncpoint 1
task2
task3
task4
syncpoint 2
task5
syncpoint 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't simple.  But the good news is that it's very well understood.

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler

Then read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software

You probably want something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Linux_Utility_for_Resource_Management

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the scripts are python the easiest solution would be to write functions that imports(and thus runs) the other scripts.  point to these functions with either the multiprocessing or threading module.  Now that you have each script running in its own process or thread, you can use condition objects and the .wait() .notify() methods to have them stop and wait on each other.

All the documentation to implement such a thing can be found here.
http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html